# Is there a Bitcoin service that works like Western Union?

Tags: transactions

I am very new to using Bitcoin.  I have never actually used it yet.  My goal is to send a payment of $100 to a trustworthy individual in China.  I was given some sort of address by this individual when I asked how/where to send payment.

Is it possible for me to simply go to a physical agent location near my address to make this payment, then have the agent send my payment to the recipient (similar to how western union and money gram work)?

I am very intimidated by how this all works.  I would love to simply do this on my own computer, but even creating a credible "wallet" has been confusing for me.

Any comments or help are greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. When posting questions, please choose a title that hints at what the question actually is, rather than a generic description like "Beginner question".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll easily find a service of the kind you describe.

But using Bitcoin directly shouldn't be too difficult. You can install a wallet on your computer such as https://electrum.org/. Then you can buy some bitcoins (the best way will depend on your location), and send them to the recipient.